# using sql to select two different date ranges in database for redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have codes as below:

```
select date
from date_table
where date between '2019-05-01' and '2019-07-31'
and date between '2020-05-01' and '2020-07-31'
```

but when i run the code above it shows no rows to display despite i run successfully when only using

```
select date
from date_table
where date between '2019-05-01' and '2019-07-31'
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want to `OR` these two date ranges:

```
SELECT date
FROM date_table
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-07-31'
    OR
    date BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-07-31';
```

ANDing together the two ranges will never return any records, since the two ranges are mutually exclusive, and any date can only fall into one of the ranges.

As a side note, if you want to include 1st May 2019 up to, and including, 31st July 2019 (with similar logic on the other range as well), then you should be using inequalities:

```
SELECT date
FROM date_table
WHERE
    date >= '2019-05-01' AND date < '2019-08-01'
    OR
    date >= '2020-05-01' AND date < '2020-08-01';
```

Comment: This code will show both years with months from 5-7 right>

Comment: Yes, it should do that.